# Syntax for calling HTTP Servlet from Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Just trying to figure out the proper syntax for making a POST to an HTTP Servlet from Flex. A Java developer gave me this URL to call:

```
http://myUrl:myPort/myProject/test/getFile/?fileId=1225
```

I want to build the the HTTPService url dynamically, meaning I pass the '1225' at the end.

My question is regarding how to translate that to MXML. Does that mean my HTTPService object looks like this?

```
<mx:HTTPService
    id="rawFileServlet"
    url="http://myUrl:myPort/myProject/test/getFile/?fileId="
    method="POST"
    showBusyCursor="true">

    <mx:request xmlns="">
        <fileId>

        </fileId>
    </mx:request>

</mx:HTTPService>
```

And my call is this:

```
params["fileId"] = 1225; httpServ.send(params);
```

Is that right? Something seems strange about it.

Here's updated code that works but doesn't allow me to trap remote errors nicely:

```
var url:String = model.fileUploadServletUrl;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        request.method = 'POST';
        request.url = url;

        var uvar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        uvar.fileId = evt.fileId;

        request.data = uvar;

        try{
            navigateToURL( request );
        }
        catch( e:Error ){
            ErrorManager.processRemoteError( 'Download Excel failed' );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you form your parameters in ActionScript in `send()` method use the following:

```
<mx:HTTPService
    id="rawFileServlet"
    url="http://myUrl:myPort/myProject/test/getFile/"
    method="POST"
    showBusyCursor="true" />
```

And you can use simple object for `params`:

```
var params:Object = {fileId: 1225};
rawFileServlet.send(params);
```

Comment: This is the correct way.  It should also be mentioned that if the URL is different than where your swf is located, you'll need a crossdomain policy file on the web server.

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm. One addendum, this URL should prompt me to download a file. It works if I copy and paste link in browser, but launching it locally from IDE, all I get is result msg back from HTTP service call. Is there a network setting I need to change or s/thing?

Comment: You need [`URLLoader` for that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html).

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm calling a script on a Java Servlet, not pointing to a specific file to download.

Comment: If result is a file it doesn't matter. Try to use `URLLoader`. It accepts [`URLVariables`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html) as [`data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data) of [`URLRequest`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html).

Comment: i'm sorry, you're right on target. I actually just did a test using FileReference.download( URLRequest ) and it worked perfectly. Sorry for doubting you at first; very helpful.

Comment: I'm updating my initial post with the code that I'm using now. The problem is that using URLLoader with URLRequest, I get the response but no prompt to download the file. I have to use navigateToUrl( URLRequest ) to get the file. The only problem with this is that I can't trap remote errors nicely. For example, an HTTPStatus 500 error will display in whatever browser window I specify.